# Input Date as MM/yyyy format in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need to put start date and end date on my page.

It will be only month and year date, with day set to 01 in the start date and to last day of month in the end date.

How can I achieve this feature?

I have tried the Ajax `MaskedEditExtender`, but when I put `99/9999` in the mask, with the `maskType="Date"`, it give me a javascript error, because the day is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are trying to validate the entry. I suggest you use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) - you'll need to write your own JavaScript for the client-side validation and another validation method for the server-side validation. All you need to do is split the string on `/` and check the first part is in the range 1..12 and the second part is a valid year.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was thinking of doing it, but i was wondering if there is already some feature to do what I want. But I came up with a solution using the ajax maskededitextender and using the ValidationExpression property of maskededitvalidator, with a regex. I also changed the maskType to 'None', so the extender don't throw me an error.